# Selecting certain tagged posts and their authors

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-error-1066

How can you join these 5 tables together:

```
tag: id, name
author: username, id
thread_tags: thread_id, tag_id
thread: id, content
author_threads: author_id, thread_id
```

(I also have a table called author_tags (tag_id, author_id), but I dont think thats needed here).

I want to select all the threads which are tagged a certain tag and their authors.

The following code returns `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tag'`

```
SELECT thread.content, author.username
FROM tag
JOIN thread_tags ON thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
JOIN tag ON thread_tags.tag_id = tag.id
JOIN author_threads ON author.id = author_threads.author_id
JOIN author ON author_threads.thread_id = thread.id
WHERE tag.name = 'arsenal'
```

**EDIT:**

This works:

```
SELECT thread.content
FROM tag
JOIN thread_tags ON tag.id = thread_tags.tag_id
JOIN thread ON thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
WHERE tag.name =  'tagged'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

However whenever I try to join authors with their threads, it throws #1066 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have joined the `tag` table twice, (thus the error) and haven't joined the `thread` table.

```
SELECT thread.content, author.username
FROM tag
  JOIN thread_tags
    ON tag.id = thread_tags.tag_id
  JOIN thread                                  --join thread (not tag again)
    ON thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
  JOIN author_threads
    ON author_threads.thread_id = thread.id     --error here too, in your query
  JOIN author
    ON author.id = author_threads.thread_id     --error here too, in your query
WHERE tag.name = 'arsenal'
```

Comment: Agree that one of the `tag`s should be `thread`, but I think it must be the first one. (You can see that from the fact that `thread` is referenced in the first join condition.)

Comment: @Andriy: yes, if we want to make minimum changes (and the query works!), we'll have to change the first `tag` -> `thread` and interchange the last two `ON...` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

why you have a tag table in your JOIN? this is why you are getting the error:

```
JOIN tag ON thread_tags.tag_id = tag.id
```

you also have table tag here:

```
FROM tag
```

tag table appeared twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have the tag table twice in your query. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT thread.content, author.username
FROM thread
LEFT JOIN thread_tags ON thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
LEFT JOIN tag ON thread_tags.tag_id = tag.id
LEFT JOIN author_threads ON author.id = author_threads.author_id
LEFT JOIN author ON author_threads.thread_id = thread.id
WHERE tag.name = 'arsenal'
```

BTW - isn't it better to store ``` author_id`` in ```thread` table ?

Comment: "*isn't it better to store `author_id` in `thread` table?*". Not if a thread can have many authors, like it's suggested by the tables structure.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'author.id' in 'on clause'